# ImportError: No module named - Using my own module in separate *.py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, importerror

### There was a missed typo that caused this error. Thanks for those who helped me see what I could not.

I've created a function in "MD2CSV.py" file to transform an XML file to an CSV file using LXML. After I got that working, I'm trying to call it from another file, the "main.py" of the project. Both files are in the same folder. When I run "main.py" I receive an error saying that main.py cannot import the MD2CSV module.

Any help for this beginner would be greatly appreciated.

This is the "main.py" file that I'm executing and using to call the MD2CSV() function.

```
import MD2CSV #TYPO CORRECTED

def main():
    MD2CSV("Metadata.xml")

#execute main()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the function that I've created in the file named "MD2CSV.py".

```
import lxml.etree as ET

def MD2CSV(file2Parse):
    md_orig = ET.parse(str(file2Parse))

    XSLField = ET.parse("Field_CSV_v01.xsl")
    XSLLookup = ET.parse("Lookup_CSV_v01.xsl")

    transformField = ET.XSLT(XSLField)
    transformLookup = ET.XSLT(XSLLookup)

    resultFieldCSV = transformField(md_orig)
    resultLookupCSV = transformLookup(md_orig)

    saveFieldCSV = open("Fields.txt","w")
    saveFieldCSV.write(str(resultFieldCSV))
    saveFieldCSV.close()

    saveLookupCSV = open("Lookups.txt","w")
    saveLookupCSV.write(str(resultLookupCSV))
    saveLookupCSV.close()
```

This is the error message that I receive when I run it through PyCharm 4.5.1 Community Edition on Xubuntu 14.04

```
/usr/bin/python3.4 /home/greg/Dropbox/PycharmProjects/XSLT-LXML-Tests/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/greg/Dropbox/PycharmProjects/XSLT-LXML-Tests/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MD2SCV
ImportError: No module named 'MD2SCV'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried to figure out how to use a "**init**.py" file to resolve this issue but all of my attempts failed. If someone knows how to construct one of these (if it would solve the problem), I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What is the "RET" for?

Comment: `MD2SCV` and `MD2CSV` are not the same, any more than your name is Gregory Lomen. :) In other words, just a simple typo.

Comment: Also, your error message clearly doesn't come from this code; `RETSMD2SCV` is not the same as either `MD2SCV` or `MD2CSV`., because it has an extra `RETS` on the beginning.

Comment: I renamed the module from "RETSMD2CSV" to "MD2CSV". I don't think that the name of the module mattered?

Comment: A TYPO!!!! 

How many hours today have I flogged on this problem over "CSV" v "SCV" typo!

I'll go hang my head in shame now.

Comment: It matters if you are trying to import it. You cant import a module if you are trying to import it by a different name. An init.py file can be empty but you need to have one so that python knows its a package.

Comment: Now the error code says "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable".

What books would anyone recommend for a true newb?

Comment: @GregoryLemon: You generally shouldn't ask a completely different followup question in comments for an existing question. In this case, the answer is trivial: `import MD2CSV` gives you access to the module `MD2CSV`, and the class inside of it `MD2CSV.MD2CSV`, but those aren't the same thing. Avoiding this confusion is part of the reason [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests using lowercase names for modules and titlecase names for classes.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert, I will go read the style guide. I'm new to this site and Python. Please forgive my etiquette clumsiness.

Comment: @GregoryLemon: No problem. As for a good book, I don't really know (I learned mostly from the official tutorial, which was a lot worse back then than it is now but still isn't great for a true newb…). And StackOverflow's help specifically notes that this site is no good for getting that kind of recommendation. You might want to try one of the [mailing lists](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo), either tutor or python-list for up-to-date info and a discussion on the pros and cons of different books.

Comment: PLEASE delete the question, @GregoryLemon .  Otherwise you are adding to your shame by wasting the time of community moderators, who have to review the close votes on this question.    (But thanks for making it **clear** at the top that this is what needs to happen to this question!).  If you don't delete it, 5 other people have to spend time to vote to close it, then more action (I don't know what) happens to delete it.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Tried to delete it. It says that I cannot because it has been answered. This is my first day on this site. Again, sorry for all of the faux pas on my first question.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Just in case you didn't see my edit. My delete attempt failed. Sorry about that.

Comment: Odd.  I wonder if we've found another thing in the world that I don't know - there are many.   I thought anyone could delete their own question.  Not to worry: something to think about for next time, and you did the right thing with the bold.  Thanks,all the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
import MD2SCV
```

to

```
import MD2CSV
```

... that will do the work :X

Comment: I don't see the difference between the two lines.

Comment: SCV -> CSV. Probably Typo.

Comment: one is "S"cv and the other is "C"sv

Comment: Downvoter: Can you please explain why?

Comment: The typo. I see it now.

Comment: I'm guessing that either (1) someone saw that your question had no explanation, and that the OP didn't even spot the difference because you didn't point it out, and decided that the answer was therefore not useful on its own, or (2) someone likes to punish people for answering questions that should obviously be closed instead because he's on a crusade (there are a lot of these people). Either way, chances are he's not going to be back.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert . Are the guidelines here suggesting that I'm not suppose to answer questions like this one?

Comment: As the OP, I accepted this answer. I didn't look close enough to the answer to have it register. This answered my question. Thanks, Infinity.

Comment: @Infinity: For (1), I think the answer would be a lot better if it explained that there was a typo. The fact that the OP didn't spot the difference and you had to go through a few comments back and forth makes it obvious the answer could have been better. I don't think it deserves a downvote for that, but different people have different standards.

Comment: @Infinity: Either way, I think this problem should be closed—it's pretty much a paradigm case of "not reproducible or simple typo"—in which case the votes don't really matter anyway.